# Relaying data between iOS devices with app in background

Tags: ios, ipad

This might be asking for the moon but here goes...

Is it possible to have an iOS app receive data and then forward it all while running in the background?

We're a restaurant currently using an ordering system that uses a main iPad as the till, with a second iPad in the kitchen to receive orders, and another third iPad used by the servers to take orders. Orders are sent to the main till which relays orders to the kitchen.

Works great... Unless someone switches app on the main till iPad to our other (necessary) hosting app, then all hell breaks loose and all orders stop getting sent.

Developer (small team) has told us it's impossible to solve but I have done some digging into recent Apple APIs that allow simple tasks to run in the background and have seen a few promising options, or perhaps it's possible via the External Accessory Framework, or even syncing via iCloud? A question for the more knowledgable than me, but is there currently a workaround to solve this that I could suggest or are they right in that it's currently impossible in iOS?

Comment: Probably would have been better to build the system as a webapp instead of a native iOS app, then use socket io for real time updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are ways to have an app in the background receive data, generally using either:

```
beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:
```

or

```
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
```

Take a look at the **[`Background Execution`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)** section in the documentation for more info...

Comment: I understand those are for short periods. I'm really looking for a longer term solution potentially over a few hours. Background Fetch seems to the best bet. Can it not just fetch data but also upload data over the network after fetching?

Comment: I'm not sure what gives you that idea; there's also an example in code using the same methods of a long-running task. Depending on the data, background fetch might be appropriate, or even push notifications work well when you want alerts associated with something as having changed or is updated.

Comment: Oh, I read someone else's question on SO that this method only tended to last a few minutes or so. So Apple would quite reasonably allow an app to continue running in background with this method for several hours? I will have to reinvestigate it.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that aspect; the duration does depend on the task. It boils down to exactly what you are ultimately needing to accomplish. Push Notifications could actually be your best option, since they can be sent as needed and have the ability to customize the data and how it's delivered as well. Your question asks "Is it possible to relay data between devices while the app is in the background", the answer is *yes*. How you do it really depends on the situation and what information needs to be relayed/updated/frequency.